# Most Efficient Way to List All $n$-bit Permutations

Tags: efficiency, permutations, storage

Suppose we are tasked with expressing a randomized list of all numbers up to but excluding $2^n$ (ie. a random list of all n-bit numbers).  What are some efficient ways to do such a listing using as few bits as possible?

**Attempt:** My thought is that the verbose listing of all $n$-bit numbers has a lot of redundancy, so if we start by listing all $2^n$ numbers, $2^{n-1}$ of those numbers will have a number that is identical except for one bit (that has been previously listed)––so we can drop the $n^{th}$ bit of those $2^{n-1}$ numbers.  Now among that same set of $2^{n-1}$ numbers, there will be $2^{n-2}$ values that will have a number  that is identical until the last *two* bits, so we can drop the $n-1^{th}$ bit of those $2^{n-2}$ numbers as well.  Continuing on iteratively, we can find $2^{n-k}$ numbers that can have the final bit dropped, with $k=1,2,3,4,...n$. Finally, there is one number that can be eliminated entirely (intuitively, this makes sense because the last number in a known set can always be determined if we know all others).

Here is an example that lists all 3-bit numbers (in increasing order):

- 000
- 00
- 010
- 0
- 100
- 10
- 110
- .

It seems like we can model the number of bits this method uses as such:
$$2^{n-1}n + 2^{n-2}(n-1) + ... + 2^1(2) + 2^{0}(1) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k(k+1) = 2^n(n-1)+1$$

(saving $2^n -1$ bits from the verbose $2^n*n$ version)

Comment: Is the output format required to be list of bits or could it be a higher level description? The input is ordered list or only number of bits? Would LFSR with added 0 (here $n$ zeros) be a valid solution?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "higher level description"–but, for example, hexadecimal would not be allowed.

Comment: If the order is predetermined and arbitrary, you need $\lceil \log_2 2^n! \rceil$ bits to describe it.

Comment: You can encode a permutation on $m$ values using a number in the range $0,\ldots,m!-1$ in many different ways. It's a nice exercise. You can think of this number from $0,\ldots,m!-1$ as encoding a number from $0,\ldots,m-1$, a number from $0,\ldots,m-2$, ..., and a number from $0,\ldots,0$.

Comment: It's a nice exercise. I haven't spelled out the details.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? I'm not sure I understand it. What do you mean by "do such a listing using as few bits as possible"? Are you really just looking for an efficient way to record a permutation of all $n$-bit words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $n$ is known from the start, you know that there are exactly $2^n!$ possible lists.  Calculate the index of your list in a lexical ordering of all permutations, and then write that number using $\lceil log_2(2^n!)\rceil$ bits.

In practice, you can come arbitrarily close to this bound using arithmetic encoding, without having to manipulate very large integers.